# Symfony DI : Circular service reference with Doctrine event subscriber

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

In order to refactor the code about the ticket notification systems, I created a Doctrine listener:

```
final class TicketNotificationListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    /**
     * @var TicketMailer
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * @var TicketSlackSender
     */
    private $slackSender;

    /**
     * @var NotificationManager
     */
    private $notificationManager;

    /**
     * We must wait the flush to send closing notification in order to
     * be sure to have the latest message of the ticket.
     *
     * @var Ticket[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    private $closedTickets;

    /**
     * @param TicketMailer        $mailer
     * @param TicketSlackSender   $slackSender
     * @param NotificationManager $notificationManager
     */
    public function __construct(TicketMailer $mailer, TicketSlackSender $slackSender, NotificationManager $notificationManager)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->slackSender = $slackSender;
        $this->notificationManager = $notificationManager;

        $this->closedTickets = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Stuff...
}
```

The goal is to dispatch notifications when a Ticket or a TicketMessage entity is created or updated trough mail, Slack and internal notification, using Doctrine SQL.

I already had a circular dependencies issue with Doctrine, so I injected the entity manager from the event args instead:

```
class NotificationManager
{
    /**
     * Must be set instead of extending the EntityManagerDecorator class to avoid circular dependency.
     *
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var NotificationRepository
     */
    private $notificationRepository;

    /**
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @param RouterInterface $router
     */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     */
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->notificationRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Notification');
    }

    // Stuff...
}
```

The manager is injected form the `TicketNotificationListener`

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    // Must be lazy set from here to avoid circular dependency.
    $this->notificationManager->setEntityManager($args->getEntityManager());
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
}
```

The web application is working, but when I try to run a command like `doctrine:database:drop` for example, I got this:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException]                                                                                                                                                                                            
  Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.dbal.default_connection", path: "doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> mailer.ticket -> twig -> security.authorization_checker -> security.authentication.manager -> fos_user.user_provider.username_email -> fos_user.user_manager".
```

But this is concerning vendor services.

How to solve this one? Why I have this error only on cli?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running cli and web on different env? Eg. console --env dev and web is hitting app.php? Clear cache manually if you are and try again.

Comment: The error message sort of implies that TicketMailer is the problem.  Does it have any connection to the database?

Comment: Vladmir: Same env and already removed the cache, this change nothing.

Comment: Cerad: The TicketMailer has a dependencies to twig which has dependencies to the authentication manager which has dependencies to the fos_user manager which has dependencies to... doctrine connection! \o/ But I would be surprised if the mailer is the problem. I got this error after adding the NotificationManager...

Comment: I cant explain why you are not seeing this in your web but the doctrine entity manager service is dependent on all of it's listeners.  Just the way Symfony implemented things.  So your ticket doctrine listener cannot have a dependency on anything that uses the doctrine entity manager or connection.  Just going to have to rethink your dependencies or possibly add your doctrine listener manually to the entity manager instead of tagging it.  You might get away with TicketMailer::setAuthenticationManager but as you can see, things start to get messy and confusing.

Comment: By the way, use @UserName when replying to a comment.  The @ triggers a notification.

Comment: Well as a "dirty" fix u can inject the entire service container and get the em from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO you are mixing 2 different concepts here:

- Domain Events (`TicketWasClosed` for example)
- Doctrine's Life-cycle Events (`PostPersist` for example)

Doctrine's event system is meant to hook into the persistence flow, to deal stuff directly related to saving to and loading from the database. It shouldn't be used for anything else.

To me it looks like what you want to happen is:

> When a ticket was closed, send a notification.

This has nothing to do with Doctrine or persistence in general. What you need is another event system dedicated to Domain Events.

You can still use the [EventManager](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.5/class-Doctrine.Common.EventManager.html) from Doctrine, but make sure you create a second instance which you use for Domain Events.

You can also use something else. Symfony's [EventDispatcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html) for example. If you're using the Symfony framework, the same thing applies here as well: don't use Symfony's instance, create your own for Domain Events.

Personally I like [SimpleBus](http://simplebus.github.io/MessageBus/), which uses objects as events instead of a string (with an object as "arguments"). It also follows the Message Bus and Middleware patterns, which give a lot more options for customization.

PS: There are a lot of really good articles on Domain Events out there. Google is your friend :)

**Example**

Usually Domain Events are recorded within entities themselves, when performing an action on them. So the `Ticket` entity would have a method like:

```
public function close()
{
    // insert logic to close ticket here

    $this->record(new TicketWasClosed($this->id));
}
```

This ensures the entities remain fully responsible for their state and behavior, guarding their invariants.

Of course we need a way to get the recorded Domain Events out of the entity:

```
/** @return object[] */
public function recordedEvents()
{
    // return recorded events
}
```

From here we probably want 2 things:

- Collect these events into a single dispatcher/publisher.
- Only dispatch/publish these events after a *successful* transaction.

With the Doctrine ORM you can subscribe a listener to Doctrine's `OnFlush` event, that will call `recordedEvents()` on all entities that are flushed (to collect the Domain Events), and `PostFlush` that can pass those to a dispatcher/publisher (only when successful).

SimpleBus provides a [DoctrineORMBridge](http://simplebus.github.io/DoctrineORMBridge/) that supplies this functionality.

Comment: Ok, but how to trigger `TicketWasClosed`? I mean, where? The ticket can be close at multiple place and I don't want to manually trigger this event on those places. The event concept would be useless in this case IMHO. Or directly from the doctrine event?

Comment: Ok I see. So it's triggering new custom events but from the doctrine listener. Could work, but it's quite bad to have to create a new system just because of dependencies issues IMHO... Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm afraid you're misinterpreting my reasoning. IMO you should create a separate event-system for a separate concept/context/responsibility: One is dedicated to _domain events_ (which you might want to publish to other (external) systems), another is dedicated to _Doctrine lifecycle events_ (which you never want to leak to the outside world). Solving your circular dependency issues is a side-effect ;)

Comment: I finally choose your solution: http://pastebin.com/Mkez82WG

And then my domain event listener does the rest. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Had the same architectural problem lately, assuming you use Doctrine `2.4+` the best thing to do is not use the `EventSubscriber` (which triggers for all events), but use `EntityListeners` on the two entities you mention.

Assuming that the behavior of both entities should be the same, you could even create one listener and configure it for both entities. The annotation looks like this:

```
/** 
* @ORM\Entity()
* @ORM\EntityListeners({"AppBundle\Entity\TicketNotificationListener"})
*/
class TicketMessage
```

Thereafter you can create the `TicketNotificationListener` class and let a service definition do the rest:

```
app.entity.ticket_notification_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Entity\TicketNotificationListener
    calls:
        - [ setDoctrine, ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'] ]
        - [ setSlackSender, ['@app.your_slack_sender'] ]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

You might not even need the entity manager here, because the entity itself is available via the `postPersist` method directly:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 */
public function postPersist($entity, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    $this->slackSender->doSomething($entity);
}
```

More info on Doctrine entity listeners: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners

Comment: I awarded you the bounty b/c I think it might be the most pragmatic one… not sure if it works at all though, too bad…

Comment: We actually have this approach working in our `prod` environment. I'd advise to not inject the entity manager, basically the listener shouldn't ever need it. Let me know if you want me to elaborate on any specific behavior.

Comment: Using EntityListener looks better indeed. But now I have another circular issues: Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_listener_resolver", path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_listener_resolver -> mailer.ticket -> twig -> security.authorization_checker -> security.authentication.manager -> fos_user.user_provider.usern  
  ame_email -> fos_user.user_manager". Seems to be another thing... Thanks for your help.